# How to write test for RepositoryFactory in Vue.js/Nuxt.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

### Summery

I've implemented RepositoryFactory pattern for API connection in Vue.js/Nuxt.js application.
https://medium.com/canariasjs/vue-api-calls-in-a-smart-way-8d521812c322

`hogeRepository.ts`

```js
import { NuxtAxiosInstance } from '@nuxtjs/axios'

type queryData = {
  q: string | null
}

export const HogeRepository = ($axios: NuxtAxiosInstance) => ({
  createResource (apiVersion: Number) {
    return `v${apiVersion}/meetings`
  },

  get (data: queryData, version = 1) {
    const url = `${this.createResource(version)}`
    return $axios.get(url, {
      params: { ...data }
    })
  },
})
```

`repository.ts`

```js
import { HogeRepository } from '~/api/hogeRepository'

export interface Repositories {
  hoge: typeof HogeRepository
}

const repositories = {
  hoge: HogeRepository
}

export const RepositoryFactory = {
  get: (key : keyof Repositories) => repositories[key]
}
```

`hoge.vue`

```
async test () {
  await RepositoryFactory.get('hoge')(this.$axios).get()
}
```

Now I'm trying to write test code for these files.
I want to know how to write test code for them.

### What I've tried

I tried to write some test code.
But it shows error on `this`.$axios saying `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

repositoryFactory.spec.ts

```js
import { RepositoryFactory } from '~/api/repositoryFactory'

describe('RepositoryFactory', () => {
  it('Should create repositories', () => {
    const repositoryFactory = RepositoryFactory.get('hoge')(this.$axios) <- error on this
  })
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the $axios to test it. Check this [link](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-asynchronous-behavior).

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: Promise.resolve('value')
}))
```